# SQL, questions about join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables in sql 2012: name and prod with structure:

**name**: `id int increment, name1 nvarchar(50)`

**prod**: `id int increment, products nvarchar(50), id_name int`

Values for table are:

name table:

```
Id   name1
1    pop
2    andi
```

prod table:

```
Id   products   id_name
1    coke       1
2    pizza      1
3    orange     2
```

I have done this query:

```
select name.name1, prod.product, prod.id_name
from name
join prod on name.id=prod.id_name
```

How can I obtain this result:

```
pop ->coke, pizza
andi->orange
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 5):

unfortunately, there's no easy way to do it in SQL Server. Known solutions are:

- xml trick (see below);
- using variable to accumulate data (don't work for multiple group rows, only with cursor);
- custom CLR aggregate;

here's xml:

```
select
    n.name1,
    stuff(
        (
         select ', ' + p.product
         from prod as p
         where p.id_name = n.id
         for xml path(''),  type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
    , 1, 2, '') as products
from name as n
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8becd/1)

here's variable:

```
declare @product nvarchar(max), @id int

select @id = 1

select @product = isnull(@product + ', ', '') + product
from prod
where id_name = @id

select name1, @product as products
from name 
where id = @id
```

[**<kbd>sql fiddle demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8becd/2)

Comment: It's working but I need to use join some like this: "select n.name1, stuff((select ', ' + p.product from prod as p 
join prod on p.id_name = n.id 
for xml path(''),  type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')
 from name as n"   but if i use join the result will be: pop->coke, coke, coke, pizza, pizza, pizza; andi->orange, orange, orange; and is not ok. Can you help me if i use Join?

Comment: What do you need that join for?

Comment: I need that join because i have a database with more tables and i use join for 3 tables, and i have some conditions. This is only an example. I resolve the problem with join in this mode:                 "select distinct n.name1, stuff((select ', ' + p.product from prod as p 
where p.id_name = n.id
for xml path(''),  type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, '')

  from name as n join prod on prod.id_name = n.id  "                  THANKS!!!!

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
SELECT
G.id,
G.name1,
stuff(
    (select cast(',' as varchar(10)) + U.product
    from prod U
    WHERE U.id_name = G.id
    order by U.product
    for xml path('')
), 1, 1, '') AS prod
FROM name G
ORDER BY G.name1 ASC
```

Answer (score 3):

[**<kbd>sqlfiddle</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/47b64/8)

```
select
n.nameid [id],
n.name [name],
count(*)[count],
    stuff(
        (
         select ', ' + p.prod
         from prodtbl as p
         where p.nameid = n.nameid
         for xml path(''),  type).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as products
from nametbl n, prodtbl p
where p.nameid = n.nameid
group by n.nameid, n.name
order by [id];
```

[image]

Comment: don't see how it's different from my answer :)

Comment: +1 small change, just wanted to give `count` info - if that is helpful for user2645263. :)